# Bypass the firewall for using the ssh command

Tags: ssh, firewall

I'm working from a cafe, and I'm thinking there's a firewall on the router preventing me from using the command `ssh 'ip address'`. Is there exists a way to bypass the firewall such as I can access the remote machine?

**P.S.** I want to access the remote machine via a local network.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is a question about a router/firewall instead of Ubuntu. You could try asking in [su] or [sf] for help with this particular issue.

Comment: The 16.10 tag is irrelevant to this question. Please only use version tags for questions that are actually restricted to that particular version.

Comment: It is not uncommon for businesses routers to block outgoing packets to port 22 (SSH). I would suggest you try changing the SSH port on the remote machine to something other than port 22, and then see if that works.

Comment: I'll try to change port. Do I need to change port on both machine?

Comment: Yes. Say, for example you changed sshd on the remote server to listen on port 2222, then your client command would become `ssh -p 2222 ip_address` (check `man ssh`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I understand that you want to access a remote machine on another location through the internet and not through a local connection.  If this is the case, you have to access the router's settings and open the port the ssh server is using for incoming connections.  There is no other way to bypass a closed port.

Comment: Is there a way to verify if the port is indeed close? In fact, I want to access the remote machine through a local connection.

Comment: The router firewall should not block local network connections unless access has been denied to certain computers using the mac address filter for example.  Those computers wouldn't be able to access the internet either though.  If you are trying to connect using the correct ssh port, then something else causes this issue probably.  You have to make sure the default port 22 hasn't been changed in the server's settings and that the server machine doesn't block that port using a software firewall, like `ufw` for example.